# yii postgresql text datatype mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, text, yii

I'm trying to insert into text datatype column in postgresql with yii.

code in migration

```
'description' => 'text'
```

when trying to

```
$model->save()
```

where model is activerecord and

```
$model->description
```

is some random string,
I get the following

```
SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text

LINE 1: SELECT 1 FROM "entry" "t" WHERE description LIMIT 1
^. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT 1 FROM "entry" "t" WHERE description LIMIT 1
```

Everything works fine for mysql database or for varchar columns
what's wrong here?

**Edit:** Apparently there are no problems with postgresql
yii activerecord->save() somehow generates wrong queries for postgres

Comment: In your `entry` table what's the `datatype` of _column_ `description` and what are the _data_ present in `description `??

Comment: @varchar datatype is text, no data present, it's a new table

Comment: `SELECT 1 FROM "entry" "t" WHERE description LIMIT 1` then for what you include `description ` in this select ??

Comment: @varchar I do not include description I just call $model->save() for yii active record

Comment: but in that error its very clear that `description ` is in your select query

Comment: @varchar I think that's how yii generate sql, it works fine for varchar datatype or for mysql for example though

Comment: post your sql for create table for `entry` table

Comment: What is the DDL for the table `entry`?

Comment: "Everything works fine for mysql database " No it doesn't, you're just lucky in this case. The query doesn't make sense, half the question is missing.